# Head and tail of files in a directory, selected by the user

Tags: shell-script, tail, head

I have this script that will show the user the head or tail of the files that are inside a set directory (currently that is set as `~/bin/new/*`).
This script works, but I would like to allow the user to not only show the head or the tail but so that they can select the directory.

The current script is written as:

```
while true;do
echo "Would you like to list the head or tail?"
    read headortail
if [[ $headortail = head ]]; then
    head -n 4 ~/bin/new/*
break
elif [[ $headortail = tail ]]; then
    tail -n 4 ~/bin/new/*
break
else
    echo "Invalid Input - Please Input head or tail"
fi
done
```

If I add another line under the first `echo` such as:

```
echo "Please type the directory"
    read dirLocation
```

How could I implement this to the script? Would I do:

```
head -n 4 $dirLocation
```

Would that work?

Comment: Almost; you probably would want to use `if [[ -d "$dirLocation" ]]; then head -n4 ${dirLocation}/*; else echo "No such directory"; fi` or the like.  There are many other improvements that could be made, such as using `select` rather than `read ... if`.

Comment: I would use command line arguments. Interactive command line programs are a pain. If it can be an argument, then it should be (except passwords, and similar). e.g. usage `script --head | --tail [directory]`

Answer (score 0):

After `read dirLocation` simply replace

```
~/bin/new/*
```

with

```
"$dirLocation"/*
```